# upgrade problem from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, 17.04, unity-greeter, unity8

I did try to upgrade the ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 17.04 using information from this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-04) :

> After switching you’ll need to run a quick update (it’ll prompt you to do this anyway) and then you’ll need to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 (yes, 16.10).
>
> `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`
>
> Once that upgrade has completed reboot, login and run the command again, this time to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04.
>
> `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

When I tried to  upgrade 16.04 to 16.10 with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` , the pc was turned off ( Mr X took off the battery ) so the upgrade was interrupted , but still everything working right and I continued upgrading to 17.04.

now I have a problem :

- when I run `sudo apt-get update` it  doesn't show all the dependencies
- when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` it return this:
  [image]

is there any way to fix these issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't now if it doomed something else on the system but it works out for my problem:

```
sudo -i                       # to be the superuser
dpkg --purge unity-plugin-scopes:amd64 url-dispatcher:amd64 url-dispatcher-tools unity8-common unity8 unity-greeter-session-broadcast unity8-desktop-session   # to remove the 7 last dependencies
```

then, remove `libunity-scopes1.0:amd64` manually cause dpkg --dpkg had some issues with this one so with command line:

```
rm -r /usr/share/doc/libunity-scopes*
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libunity-scopes*
rm /usr/share/apport/package-hooks/libunity-scopes1.0.py
rm /var/crash/libunity-scopes*
```

then you can use:

```
dpkg --purge libunity-scopes1.0:amd64
apt-get install -f
apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm able to upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04 by following command sequence.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then tried the following command as suggested in internet

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

result : System is up-to date, actually newer version available

Then tried to find which version available by issuing this command

```
thiru@ubuntu:~/work$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '17.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

So, run this command to upgrade successfully as suggested by command output.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After this my Ubuntu updated to 17.04 successfully.